# "Actual and formal argument lists differ in length" error in android studio

Tags: android

Complete Error

```
mContentsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(ContentsViewModel.class);
                             ^
constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner,Factory) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStore,Factory) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)**
```

Error cause: `this` in below line:

> ```
> mContentsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ContentsViewModel.class);
> ```

[Check image for clear understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG3Be.png)

Comment: Can you include your `dependencies` block of your `build.gradle`? It looks like you're using an old version of Lifecycle that doesn't have the single argument `ViewModelProvider` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you have it there, it is perceived by compiler as wrong arguments passed to constructor. Without longer explanation, try this:

```
mContentsViewModel = ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(ContentsViewModel.class);
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, remove new, like this: mContentsViewModel = ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(ContentsViewModel.class);